# Install Debian To USB With State Saving

Tags: linux, usb, debian

I want to install Debian on a flash drive, but have it operate just the same as if I installed it on a HDD/SDD. So far, all the tutorials/write-ups I can find are just how to make a "live" version, which is no different than booting from a live CD/DVD. Once I reboot, anything I did is gone, it's not saved it's just to try the OS.

What I am looking to do is have the OS installed as if it were a regular installation. I don't care to move the thumb drive to another computer and run it, so I'm not worried about the installation being locked to hardware specifics of my machine. This is just my alternative to buying another SSD, or dual booting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the exact same thing, by installing Debian like normal from CD onto the USB stick.

The Debian installer should pick up the USB stick as a hard drive and allow you to install onto the USB stick as if it were a hard drive. It's easier if you don't have any hard drives already in the machines though.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to give that a try. Didn't figure that would work. I guess I'll just pull the plug on my existing drives during the install.

Comment: You'll want a reliable USB stick as well. I've killed a couple doing this so far.

Comment: Thanks, I've just ordered a kingston 64 gig drive + usb 3.0 adapter (sadly, I've got a first gen i7 on evga x58 SLI LE, so no 3.0 built in.) :)

Comment: What do you figure killed the drives? Removing/installing them or just the read/write abuse?

Comment: I'm assuming the write abuse, though I didn't really bother to do any investigation.