# Install Debian to USB without unplugging Hard Drives

Tags: linux, debian, usb-flash-drive, grub

As the poster of the following question
[Install Debian To USB With State Saving](https://superuser.com/questions/744488/install-debian-to-usb-with-state-saving)

I want to install Debian TO a USB drive. The problem is that in said question is said to make the process easier if the hard drives are unplugged. This way the installation process it is said to install the bootloader to the USB drive without trouble.

**This cannot be achieved with a laptop and I was looking for a less 'hacky' way to achieve this.**

I used the graphic install option from the Jessie amd64 iso (from another USB, built using the dd utility) and everything seemed ok. It installed to the USB and when I was asked to install GRUB I pointed to the USB where I was installing.

Now, when I try to boot from said USB drive I get a blank prompt (just blinking cursor) without possibility of input.

So,
**any way to make a functional Debian install on a USB drive without kidnapping my friend's desktop computer?**

Other Links I used
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1w03j8/run_debian_from_flash_drive/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Install Debian to the USB flash drive from a Linux guest OS running inside a virtual machine, running in VirtualBox or VMware. Create a new guest OS, if you mess up the bootloader of the guest OS when installing Debian, you can simply delete the guest OS when you're done with it.

Comment: Is there a way without VMs? I am always into learning new stuff, but right now it seems it would be easier to just kidnap my friend's box and pull those buses before the install.

Comment: Well, I finally asked my friend for help. He wasn't very pleased but I got Debian on a pendrive, which is great to have.
I haven't tested your answer @karel, but I will eventually. Thanks.